# Send json array to add multiple records in mysql to php script using volley in android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am trying to add multiple records in database i am sending json array using string request method in volley in android to php script to add those records.But haven't getting the result of json array in php. I just want to add multiple records in mysql that why sending json array to script to add those records by fetching all data in it

**Here is Insert Data function**

```
private void InsertData() {

if(arrayList.size()>0) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "list not null "+i+arrayList.size(), 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//for (i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside for loop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.insert_macthes,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);


                        if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        dis = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MyMatchas.this,
                                "Error time out",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        //TODO
                        Toast.makeText(MyMatchas.this,
                                "Auth Error time out",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        //TODO
                        Toast.makeText(MyMatchas.this,
                                "Server Error time out",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        //TODO
                        Toast.makeText(MyMatchas.this,
                                " Network Error time out",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MyMatchas.this,
                                "Parse Error time out",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //TODO
                    }

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            for(i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
            {
                Log.v("fetching record:",arrayList.get(i).getId());
                arr[i]="dog_id"+arrayList.get(i).getId()+"dog_name"+arrayList.get(i).getDog_name()+"score"+arrayList.get(i).getDog_score()+"user_id"+ String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MyMatchas.this).getUserid());
                try {
                    //Log.v("put in json:",arrayList.get(i).getId());
                    jsonObject.put("dog_id",arrayList.get(i).getId());
                    jsonObject.put("dog_name",arrayList.get(i).getDog_name());
                    jsonObject.put("score",arrayList.get(i).getDog_score());
                    jsonObject.put("user_id",String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(MyMatchas.this).getUserid()));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("error exceptiion:",arrayList.get(i).getId());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                array.put(jsonObject);
            }
            HashMap<String ,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
            Log.v("All data:",jsonObject.toString());
            Log.v("json object data:",array.toString());
            params.put("params",array.toString());

            return params;
        }
    };


    // Creating RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyMatchas.this);

    // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    // }
  // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dis,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

**Here is the Php script**

```
   <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","m","rt","Friend");

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$arr = $_POST['params'];





 $json = json_decode($arr,true);
    echo $json;
foreach($json as $obj){

$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Match_list (dog_id,score,dog_name,User_ID) values 
   ('$obj->dog_id','$obj->dog_name','$obj->score','$obj->user_id')";

   if($con->query($Sql_Query) === TRUE)
   {

    die(json_encode(array("success"=>1,"message"=>"Data Added 
 Successfuly")));



   }


      }


   }

  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: This is because the query fails and never resolves to `true`. "INSERT INTO Match_list (dog_id,score,dog_name,User_ID) values 
   ('$obj->dog_id','$obj->dog_name','$obj->score','$obj->user_id')" is still a string with no substitution. Try wrapping your variables in {} `...VALUES ('{$obj->dog_id}', '{$obj->dog_name}'...` or concatenate them instead `...VALUES'. $obj->dog_id . "', '". $obj->dog_name ."...`

Comment: Make sure to test your query by printing it out and trying it manually in your sql client

Comment: Still the same problem not getting data plz help me out and also only the last list data in arraylist is on the json array i have seen using log message in android

Comment: What's the result of `echo $Sql_Query` after the line `$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO...`?

Comment: I have tried it manually data is adding but i think it is not getting json array from android volley string request method and also i have checked in json array that [] square bracket is not in json array coming from android

Comment: plz help me out i am stuck don't know what to do

Comment: What's the result of echo $Sql_Query after the line $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new object for every time for holding new values

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
 JSONObject jsonObject;
 GettingVaccineData gettingVaccineData;
 for (int i = 0; i < vaccineData.size(); i++) {
   jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   gettingVaccineData = vaccineData.get(i);
   try {

     jsonObject.put("LCID", reqResponse);
     jsonObject.put("LVID", gettingVaccineData.getID());
     jsonObject.put("LVNAME", gettingVaccineData.getNAME());
     jsonObject.put("LSCHEDULE", scheduleDays.get(i));
     jsonObject.put("LGIVEN", "NULL");
     jsonObject.put("LSTATUS", "not given");
     jsonObject.put("LHOSPITAL", "NULL");


   } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   array.put(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access values like this:

```
echo $json[0]["dog_id"];
```